# File_get_contents doesn't import php?

Tags: php, file-get-contents

I have this code:

```
    elseif($pagina == "agenda")
{
    $html = file_get_contents("template/index.php");
    $html = str_replace("%content%",file_get_contents("template/agenda.php"),$html);
    $html = str_replace("%current2%",'class="current"',$html);
    $html = str_replace("%sidebar%",file_get_contents("template/sidebar/sidebar_nieuws.php"),$html);
}
```

On the page "agenda.php" is a normal php script. This does work when I open agenda.php directly, but when I open it with this code, the code doesn't work. I think file_get_contents doesn't work on php? What is an alternative?

(Sorry for my bad english ;)..)

Comment: `file_get_contents` gets the contents of a file (surprise!), this function doesn't execute code in a file.

Comment: What exactly does "doesn't work" mean? What do you get and what do you expect?

Comment: What are you trying to do here? My guess is you need `require()` possibly in conjunction with output buffering. But its hard to tell

Comment: `file_get_contents` does exactly what it's supposed to do: it loads the contents of the file. If the contents contain PHP code, then `$html` will contain PHP code too. If you want to have the output of the PHP file, you can use `include` and catch the output.

Comment: Okay, I want to replace the %content% with the contents of template/agenda.php. I want the code on that place to be in the index.php page. So that it runs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use [output buffering](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.outcontrol.php). It's effective in this kind of scenario.

```
$html = file_get_contents("template/index.php");
$arr = array();

ob_start();
include_once('template/agenda.php');
$file = ob_get_contents(); //$file now stores the rendered output (after PHP has run) of template/agenda.php
ob_end_clean();
$arr['agenda'] = $file;

$html = str_replace("%content%", $arr['agenda'], $html);
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to run the php code. Then you can include your php file:

```
include('path/to/file.php');
```

Comment: If I replace that into my script, i get this:

elseif($pagina == "agenda")
{
 $html = file_get_contents("template/index.php");
 $html = str_replace("%content%",include('template/agenda.php'),$html);

but then it works, but the page isn't displayed as it should

Comment: @Jesse First of all i really don't understand why you would check on what page you are with if($pagina == "agenda"). and Do you load all parts of the page with another php file?

Comment: Yes, first the page loads a template (template/index.php), after that it loads the content of the page. In the content is the php code on another page.

Answer (score 0):

if you want  to change php code from file before executing then in the end run eval($html);

Comment: Do you mean this?

elseif($pagina == "agenda")
{
 $html = file_get_contents("template/index.php");
 $html = str_replace("%content%",file_get_contents("template/agenda.php"),$html);
 $html = str_replace("%current2%",'class="current"',$html);
 $html = str_replace("%sidebar%",file_get_contents("template/sidebar/sidebar_nieuws.php"),$html);
 eval($html);
}

This doesn't work..

Comment: @Jesse in most cases you should use include, if you have pure html after all proces just echo it, and if you have php in string that you want to process you use eval, (many hosts block eval as not safe function). you dont provide any errors or debug information, just doesnt work, so we cannot gues what is your problem.

Comment: Okay, but how has the code to be with the eval($html). I don't understand that part.

Comment: @Jesse eval() - is used to "run code" from string, not just display it, so is needed if  you want it to actually work...  but in this case answer of ʰᵈˑ is much nicer.